# Shopware 5 development setup for windows 10

Tags: docker, installation, windows-10, vagrant, shopware

I've been trying to get a Shopware 5 development setup up and running on my Win 10 PC, for the last few days, but without success.

I've tried with vagrant, docker or plain old Xampp, but I've never been able to get to the DemoShop page.
Either I keep on getting PHP errors during the Shopware setup, or I won't reach the server ever.
(get error on missing or outdated library, another one, one more, then a PHP syntax error in the shopware/recovery/instals files)
I've followed 4-5 different tutorials by now and I was wandering if there are Shopware developers here, that maybe could help with / suggest an easy-to-install setup.

I'm mostly trying to get this up and running on my pc, to learn this environment, because in a month or so, I'll start working for a new company, and I wanted to get ahead.

Thank you very much, if you have any questions I'll be happy to answer.

Comment: How have you tried with vagrant? You can use this Vagrant box and create your own virtual host and use it, i am using it and running multiple sites of different shopware version of 5 and 6 as well
https://github.com/JarJarBernie/jimmybox

Comment: While I posted dockware as straightforward solution due to your dev requirement, there is also the [shopware-docker](https://github.com/shyim/shopware-docker/) setup. It is provided by Shopware's core developer shyim, who recently added shopware 5 to the `create-project` options. Windows setup is described here: https://shyim.me/blog/shopware-environment-windows/

Answer (score 1):

There are different docker setups for shopware. The most straighforward, out of the box solution is [dockware](https://dockware.io/), which also supports Shopware 5 and has been reported to work on Windows.

You can pull [from dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/layers/dockware/dev/5.6.9/images/sha256-d6abc3dba66da3a3be679df97cb0009aeb6146d0c6f39e27f2430d925a549112?context=explore) or use docker-compose to do so.

This is my `docker-compose.yml` based on the dockware documentation. I only tested on Ubuntu so far.

```
version: "3"

services:
    shopware:
        image: dockware/dev:5.6.9
        container_name: shopware
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "22:22"
            # Admin Watcher Port
            - "8888:8888"
            # Storefront Watcher Port
            - "9999:9999"
        environment:
            - PHP_VERSION=7.4
            - XDEBUG_ENABLED=1
        volumes:
            - "db_volume:/var/lib/mysql"
            - "shop_volume:/var/www/html"
volumes:
    db_volume:
        driver: local
    shop_volume:
        driver: local
```